# Set dictionary values based on range

Tags: python, dictionary, range

```
index = {
    u'when_air': 0,
    u'chrono': 1,
    u'age_marker': 2,
    u'name': 3
}
```

How can I make this more beautiful (and clear) way than just manually setting each value?

like:

```
index = dict_from_range(
    [u'when_air', u'chrono', u'age_marker', u'name'],
    range(4)
)
```

Comment: Your index looks like enum. If it really is, you should use the `enum` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can feed the results of [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) to the builtin [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> names = [u'when_air', u'chrono', u'age_marker', u'name']
>>> print(dict(zip(names, range(4))))
{'chrono': 1, 'name': 3, 'age_marker': 2, 'when_air': 0}
```

`zip()` will return a list of tuples, where each tuple is the *ith* element from `names` and `range(4)`. `dict()` knows how to create a dictionary from that.

Notice that if you give sequences of uneven lengths to `zip()`, the results are truncated. Thus it might be smart to use `range(len(names))` as the argument, to guarantee an equal length.

```
>>> print(dict(zip(names, range(len(names)))))
{'chrono': 1, 'name': 3, 'age_marker': 2, 'when_air': 0}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dict comprehension together with the built-in function `enumerate` to build the dictionary from the keys in the desired order.

Example:

```
keys = [u'when_air', u'chrono', u'age_marker', u'name']
d = {k: i for i,k in enumerate(keys)}
print d
```

The output is:

```
{u'age_marker': 2, u'when_air': 0, u'name': 3, u'chrono': 1}
```

---

Note that with Python 3.4 the `enum` module was added. It may provide the desired semantics more conveniently than a dictionary.

---

For reference:

- http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

```
index = {k:v for k,v in zip(['when_air','chrono','age_marker','name'],range(4))}
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
#keys = [u'when_air', u'chrono', u'age_marker', u'name']

from itertools import count
print dict(zip(keys, count()))
```